# .csv file reading from a specified URL

Tags: java, csv

I am using this java program to read a `.csv` file from a specified URL. The only problem with this program is that it does not read last 64 records from the csv file into `myHello.csv` file. Here is the program.

```
package com.aamir;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class TestGetCSV {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url12  = new URL("https://wd5-impl-.com/ccx/service/customreport2/-ProjectsFE/YIN.05-get?format=csv" );
            URLConnection uc = url12.openConnection();
            String userpass = "username" + ":" + "password";
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());

            uc.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
            /* HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)uc;
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
            */

            InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader buff= new BufferedReader(inStream);

            String content2 = null;

            BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D:/myHello.csv"));
            while ((content2 = buff.readLine()) != null) {

                bf.write(content2);
                bf.newLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){

            System.out.print("Exception");
        }
        System.out.println("done");

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to expose what may be a proprietary URL to the entire world?

Comment: @dcsohl - it required authentication to view the file... not that I tried or anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Ultimus mentioned you are reading buffer two times and writing it only once. also make sure you close the reader and writer, that way they will force flush and everything will be complete.

Comment: I removed one readLine() inside of while loop, but its still not displaying the last 64 items.

Comment: Use, buffer.close() , bf.close() methods outside loop.

Comment: @ thanks a lot dude, i closed all the streams and now its working fine thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `while` loop you read a line that you don't need to and thus you are skipping lines when the `while` statement is re-evaluated.

Comment: Good catch but I'm not sure it explains the behaviour. He said the last 64 lines were missing - this problem would make every other line disappear, I would think. **ETA**: And now he's changed it so this problem isn't in the code anymore.

Comment: @dcsohl I removed one readLine() from while loop but its still not showing last 64 records.

Comment: Did you follow @Santhosh suggestion about properly flushing and closing all your IO classes?